# Color background of datatable cell based on shiny user input

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am using datatable from DT library for user inputs from my Shinyapp.
Now I would like to color the background of the datatable cell based on user inputs.

Here is the code of what I have got so far:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = 'Radio buttons in a table',
    DT::dataTableOutput('foo'),
    verbatimTextOutput('sel'), verbatimTextOutput('x2')

  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    x <- data.table( 'Breed Split' = paste0("F",rep(0:16)), Friesian = rep(1,17), Cross = rep(2,17), Jersey = rep(3,17) ,
                     checked=c(rep("Friesian",9),rep("Cross",5),rep("Jersey",3))
    )

    x[, Friesian := sprintf( '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s" %s/>', `Breed Split`, x[, Friesian],ifelse("Friesian"==x[, checked],"checked" ,""))]
    x[, Cross := sprintf( '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s" %s/>', `Breed Split`, x[, Cross],ifelse("Cross"==x[, checked],"checked" ,"" ))]
    x[, Jersey := sprintf( '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s" %s/>', `Breed Split`, x[, Jersey] ,ifelse("Jersey"==x[, checked],"checked" ,""))]

    output$foo = DT::renderDataTable(
      x[,-c("checked")], escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', server = FALSE, rownames=FALSE,
      options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE),
      callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
                    var $this = $(this.node());
                    $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
                    $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');
  });
                    Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
                    Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
    )

    output$sel = renderPrint({ sapply(x$`Breed Split`, function(i) input[[i]]) })

    }
    )
```

**Cell background color for selected breed:**

Friesian: red 
Cross: green  
Jersey: blue

In other words, I need to apply `formatStyle()` within `DT::renderDataTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a small example, where the background color of selected cells changes based on user input. I hope this helps!

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  dataReactive <- reactive({
      return(mtcars[mtcars$gear==input$gear,])
  })

  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    df <- head(mtcars,100)

      if(input$gear==1) color="red"
      if(input$gear==2) color="blue"
      if(input$gear==3) color="green"
      if(input$gear==4) color="lightblue"

    DT::datatable(df) %>% formatStyle(c("mpg", "cyl", "disp"),
                                      backgroundColor = color)
  })

})
```

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
 selectInput("gear","Select gear:", choices = c(1,2,3,4))
    ),
    mainPanel(
                DT::dataTableOutput("table1")
    )
  )
))
```

Comment: Thanks Florian, it helps... Really appreciate your time and effort!

Comment: No problem, happy I could help!